# How to use C# Facebook SDK call ids_for_business api?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

fackbook SDK version:6.0.10.0

.net framework: 4.0

I want to get ids_for_business data ,but after click button2.
I got a error msg is " (OAuthException - #12) (#12) ids_for_business requires version v2.0 or higher ".
How to use facebook sdk call ids_for_business api or other method in c#?

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var fb = new FacebookClient();
  dynamic result = fb.Get("/me/ids_for_business", new
                          {
    client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    access_token = Session["at"].ToString(),
    redirect_uri = "http://localhost:34025/WebForm1.aspx"
  });
  Label1.Text = "business ids:<br/>" + result.data;

}
```

-

```
'/' 應用程式中發生伺服器錯誤。

(OAuthException - #12) (#12) ids_for_business requires version v2.0 or higher

描述: 在執行目前 Web 要求的過程中發生未處理的例外狀況。請檢閱堆疊追蹤以取得錯誤的詳細資訊，以及在程式碼中產生的位置。 

例外狀況詳細資訊: Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #12) (#12) ids_for_business requires version v2.0 or higher

原始程式錯誤: 


行 72:         {
行 73:             var fb = new FacebookClient();
行 74:             dynamic result = fb.Get("/me/ids_for_business", new
行 75:             {
行 76:                 client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

原始程式檔: c:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\WebForm1.aspx.cs    行: 74 

堆疊追蹤: 


[FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #12) (#12) ids_for_business requires version v2.0 or higher]
   Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags) +1158
   Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType) +737
   Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters, Type resultType) +19
   Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters) +15
   WebApplication3.WebForm1.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\sryku2000\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\WebForm1.aspx.cs:74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9633194
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

版本資訊: Microsoft .NET Framework 版本:4.0.30319; ASP.NET 版本:4.0.30319.34237
```

Comment: `An unhandled exception occurred during the request. Please review the stack trace for more information errors` For those whose first thoughts was...what that encrypted message means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call api should add /v2.0 at api url.

```js
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var fb = new FacebookClient();
  dynamic result = fb.Get("/v2.0/me/ids_for_business", new
  {
    client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    access_token = Session["at"].ToString(),
    redirect_uri = "http://localhost:34025/WebForm1.aspx"
  });
  Label1.Text = "business ids:<br/>" + result.data;

}
```